# DXUT GetVersionEx error

Tags: directx, directx-11

I'm learning dx11 and I have been trying to import 3D models into my little game, I have been trying to copy the import method from the DX11 HLSL sample, so I copied the DXUT folder into my project, but for some reason It's giving me an that 'GetVersionEx' is depraciated. I am a begginer programmer, I looked into the problem and apparentl I should be using 'VerifyVersionInfo' I looked at examples but I don't know how to use them to fix it using that.

And I'm wondering why is this error is not coming up when I try to run the Sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to know is that the venerable DirectX SDK has been deprecated, and as you are using VS 2013 or VS 2015 based on the warning you are getting, you already have the Windows 8 SDK which has most of what you need to get started. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) for more information, and take a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx) and [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog.aspx).

The warning you are getting from VS 2013/2015 about `GetVersionEx` is an unrelated but important issue. The fact that you are seeing it when building DXUT from the legacy DirectX SDK is because that code hasn't been updated since VS 2010 was shipped. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074.aspx) and [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/10/manifest-madness.aspx).

You have a number of options for getting utility code for Direct3D 11.

- The latest version of DXUT can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DXUT). This version does not require the legacy DirectX SDK to build and works with VS 2013 and VS 2015. For more on why you might or might not want to use DXUT can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/DXUT/wiki).
- Similarly the latest version of Effects for Direct3D 11 is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11), and again works on VS 2013 / 2015. More information and a number of important disclaimers can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11/wiki).
- If you are starting fresh, I recommend you avoid using DXUT or FX11, and instead focus on using the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK). See the [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) for it including the [Rendering a model](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Rendering-a-model) lesson.
- For model and texture processing, you should see the [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh), [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex), and [Content Exporter](https://github.com/walbourn/contentexporter) projects.

Comment: oh man thank you so much for that, I wish I found the DirectXTK few months ago, this would save me frp,  tears and depression. I really appreciate this! thank you!!!! :) :) :) I am so happy